# How to get access to the logger from another module?

Tags: python, logging

I am having issues in getting access to the logger created from main program from another module.

For example:

In package 'common" I have a module "util01.py" and I have a function get_logger:

### util01.py

```
import logging
def get_logger(file_name,logger_level):

    # get logger
    logger=logging.getLogger(__name__)
    # set desired level
    logger.setLevel(logger_level)=
    # Get needed formatter
    formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s %(module)s %(lineno)d %(levelname)s %(message)s')
    # Get the log file handler
    fh = logging.FileHandler(file_name, mode = 'w')
    # Apply formatter and level to log file handler
    fh.setFormatter(formatter)
    logger.addHandler(fh)
    return logger
```

### In main.py, I create that logger:

```
import logging
import OSLCHelper

my_logger = util01.get_logger('c:\\temp\\test1.log', logging.INFO)
```

In main.py, the my_logger has proper visibility.
From main, I want to execute a function from another module e.g. function from OSLCHelper.py.

```
return OSCLHelper.get_something(var1)
```

### Now, I have another module e.g. OLSCHelper.py with following code

```
import logging
from common import util01

get_something(var1):
my_logging.info("i am in getsomething method") // my_logging does not exist
```

Unfortunately. I don't have access to "my_logger" variable. It does log any statement in the test1.log file.

How to get access to "my_logger" from different modules? Any best practices?

Please help

I tried the above and it did not work

Comment: Do your logging setup on the root logger, or at least a parent of the namespace you are planning on using for your entire program. Children will inherit the attributes. Will post a full answer later maybe.

Answer (score 2):

From [`logging.getLogger()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.getLogger):

> All calls to this function with a given name return the same logger instance. This means that logger instances never need to be passed between different parts of an application.

So one solution would be to replace

```
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
```

with

```
logger = logging.getLogger("OLSC")
```

or any other string that makes sense, I'm guessing.

Then you can always "ask" the logging module for the logger associated with that name, from any module:

```
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger("OLSC")
```